# IIS Localhost Website and Webmaster Email

Tags: php, asp.net, iis, ssl, dyndns

I am running IIS 8.5 on Windows 8.1 ProWMC (**not** Server 2012) and I have successfully set up IIS (I have enabled ALL Windows Features from Control Panel), so that `http://localhost:80/` displays my content.

However, I want to have a webmaster email account (root@localhost.com or something similar) so as to issue an SSL certificate for my domain on CACert (I have a Dynamic DNS domain, particularly "No-IP"). How can I set up an "email account" for my DDNS?

Comment: Are you asking about a POP3 server? IINM that's no longer supported (or should I say, was last supported in W2K3)...or better yet, move your question over to http://serverfault.com for better suggestions...

Comment: @EdSF I believe it should be a POP3 Server, but can you point somewhere to confirm that it is not supported? And on another glance, how can I issue an SSL certificate without verification of my DDNS domain (CACert **requires** a verification e-mail to be sent!) Finally, I posted a copy of the question [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/630945/iis-localhost-website-and-webmaster-email).

Comment: There _used_ to be a POP3 service (native) in Windows Server. I believe last one was in 2003. You can install 3rd party servers. But I don't understand the connection you are trying to make with SSL?

Comment: @EdSF I am trying to get a certificate signed from a 3rd party (CACert in this case, as it is absolutely free). So, CACert in its website requires e-mail verification (it sends a code to your domain's email and you take this back to the service). So, I need a working e-mail for localhost and because I have DDNS, I can then pass it to my DDNS domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the perfect and free fully-supporting SSL e-mail server program: [hMailServer](https://www.hmailserver.com/). It is easy enough to setup an email account from there!